# Flashing cells in excel despite conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code below which makes cells within a predefined range, flash color from white to red.

For my purposes, I need this code to work only on cells that have certain values in them - for example any cell that has a numerical value below 50.

The code that works on the entire range is as follows

```
Public NextFlash As Double
Public Const FR As String = "Sheet1!B3:D6"
Sub StartFlashing()

If Range(FR).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
Range(FR).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
Else
Range(FR).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
NextFlash = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Application.OnTime NextFlash, "StartFlashing", , True
End Sub
Sub StopFlashing()
Range(FR).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
Application.OnTime NextFlash, "StartFlashing", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: ... what is your question?

Comment: @enderland question was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to look at each cell.

Another option to avoid looking at each cell would be to alter your range `"Sheet1!B3:D6"` so that it only was set to cells below 50. But this would require constant tracking and re-evaluating the range for changes with events.

So for a 12 cell range, the loop approach below should suffice.

```
Public NextFlash As Double
Public Const FR As String = "Sheet1!B3:D6"

Sub StartFlashing()
Dim rng1 As Range
For Each rng1 In Range(FR).Cells
    If rng1.Value < 50 Then
        If rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Else
            rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Else
        rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End If
Next

NextFlash = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Application.OnTime NextFlash, "StartFlashing", , True
End Sub

Sub StopFlashing()
    Range(FR).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Application.OnTime NextFlash, "StartFlashing", , False
End Sub
```